# Can't send any request inside docker container

Tags: python, docker, flask, linux-mint

I am developing a Flask application with Docker setup. My Os is Linux Mint. Suddenly can't send any request from my application. It's showing error like this:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.kickbox.io', port=443): 
Max retries exceeded with url: /v2/verify?email=harun1393%40gmail.com&timeout=6000 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f71b5e89c90>: 
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution'))
```

ping google.com is working fine from my OS but showing **Temporary failure in name resolution** inside docker container.
docker exec -it web /bin/bash

```
root@b72e895be44a:/web# ping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

/etc/resolve.conf from OS:

```
nameserver 192.168.0.1
```

/ect/resolve.conf inside docker container

```
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0
```

cat /etc/docker/daemon.json

```
{
    "dns": ["192.168.0.1", "8.8.8.8"]
}
```

I used host network in docker-compose.yml, but result is same.

```
website:
#    network_mode: host
    build:
      context: .
      network: host

    container_name: web
```

I have tried a lot, but couldn't solve my problem.

Comment: Have  you tried restarting  your server or pc. I thinks, your docker0 veth got hanged. If not work then reinstall  docker and check

Comment: I did both. removed docker completely and reinstalled it. but same problem.